# Import issues with 3D model from Blender to web

Tags: texturing, gltf

I am new to 3D modeling and 3D for the web in general. I created my very first model in Blender. Once finished, I tried to export it via ThreeJS. The textures became terrible and some of them didn't show up. Then, I tried it on a model viewer like https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ and the model displays exactly the same as with ThreeJS. Do you have any advice or suggestions?

My export is in .gltf file format.

My model on Blender:

[image: model on Blender]

My Model on web:

[image: Model on web]

Comment: Looks like you have doubled objects there, the one you want with textures and one without. Do you have an older version which has disabled visibility in viewport and/or render? This property might not be transferred to different formats so those hidden objects become visible.

Comment: In addition to Gordon's comment you may find that https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures applies here...

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will explore all of this !